# "..cannot be inferred from the usage." How can I insert both a where and an orderby expression into this sqlite query?

Tags: linq, sqlite, mono, xamarin.android

I've been following the [Tasky Case Study](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/cross_platform/Case_Studies/Case_Study%3a_Tasky) on the MonoDroid website, but I've run into a wall whilst creating a filtering and ordering query. I was wondering if somebody could explain where I might be going wrong please? I'm probably doing something completely backwards!

I get the error:

> The type arguments for method 'ICanTalk.BusinessLayer.Services.WordServices.Find(System.Func, System.Func, bool, int, int)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I have the following code in one of my repositories, hopefully what I'm trying to do is kind of clear. I haven't been able to build it yet to test to see if it works though:

```
  public static IEnumerable<Word> Find<T,U>(Func<Word, bool> whereClause, Func<Word,U> orderBy, bool ascending, int show, int page)
  {
      int currentPage = page;
      int resultsPerPage = show;
      int skip = currentPage*show;

      var result = ascending
                       ? me.db.Find<Word>().Where(whereClause).OrderBy(orderBy).Take(resultsPerPage).Skip(skip)
                       : me.db.Find<Word>().Where(whereClause).OrderByDescending(orderBy).Take(resultsPerPage).Skip(skip);

      return result;

  }
```

From my services I call this method from here:

```
  public static IList<Word> Find<T>(Func<Word, bool> whereClause, Func<Word,DateTime> orderBy, bool ascending, int show, int page)
  {
      return WordRepository.Find<Word, DateTime>(whereClause, orderBy, ascending, show, page).ToList();
  }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a call from an event handler within MonoDroid like:

```
 var wordTest = WordServices.Find(x => x.ChildId == 3, x => x.AddedAt, true, 5, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had it *almost* right, I stripped it down to the basics and worked my way back up and came up with the following (compare to original if you're interested).

**SQLiteDatabase.cs**

(not in original post - I scaled the query clauses right down to a reusable method in my generic handler):

```cs
   public IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(Func<T, bool> whereClause, int resultsToSkip, int resultsToShow)
          where T : BusinessLayer.Contracts.IBusinessEntity, new()
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            return Table<T>().Where(whereClause).Skip(resultsToSkip).Take(resultsToShow).ToList();
        }
    }
```

**WordRepository.cs**

```
    public static IEnumerable<Word> Find<T>(Func<Word, bool> whereClause, int resultsToSkip, int resultsToShow)
        where T : BusinessLayer.Contracts.IBusinessEntity, new()
    {
        var result = me.db.Find<Word>(whereClause, resultsToSkip, resultsToShow);

        return result;
    }
```

**WordServices.cs**

By this point I'm wondering why there exists a need for so many layers - will definitley look to refactor in the morning.

```
    public static IList<Word> Find<T, U>(Func<Word, bool> whereClause, Func<Word, U> orderBy, bool ascending,  int show, int page)
    {
        int resultsToShow = show;
        int resultsToSkip = show * (page - 1);

        var result = ascending ? WordRepository.Find<Word>(whereClause, resultsToSkip, resultsToShow).OrderBy(orderBy)
                               : WordRepository.Find<Word>(whereClause, resultsToSkip, resultsToShow).OrderByDescending(orderBy);

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

**Originating Call**

```
   var wordTest1 = WordServices.Find<Word, DateTime>(x => x.ChildId == 1, x => x.AddedAt, true, 5, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your methods are generic `Find<T,U>` and `Find<T>` - but you don't seem to be using the type `T` anywhere in your method definition. Was `T` expected to be the type `Word` ?
`U` is used once in the orderBy where elsewhere you're using `bool` - which of those usages is a mistake?

Can you try replacing `Word` with `T` in your definitions, and `bool` with `U` (if that's what you meant to do) and then when you're calling the method actually call it with the correct type ?

```
var wordTest = WordServices.Find<Word>(x => x.ChildId == 3,
                                       x => x.AddedAt, 
                                       true, 5, 1);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. It's a bit confusing looking back at it actually hrrrm. The U was supposed to represent an OrderBy by any property of T. That is, U could either have been T.AddedAt to OrderBy the date it was added, or T.ChildId or something along those lines. I've scaled it right back for now, trying to build it up from the bottom again and see if I can get it working! Cheers again